# Making a custom HomeScreen GUI with Kodi

Tags: kodi

I know Kodi is Open-source and one of my buddies was talking to me about it one day saying you could customize Kodi where you can redesign the home screen environment as in making it like a kiosk screen with apps that you would want to display and what not.

I am not talking about a custom skin but actually messing with the code and adding/deleting apps or buttons.

Can this be done?

Comment: My not be the perfect solution, but you can take a look at lots of build here, there are also some cool tutorials https://seo-michael.co.uk/best-kodi-builds-2016/

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to be a little clearer what you want to build. There are various skins that have kiosk modes, but I don't think that's what you want.